# Best practice for class member initialization

Tags: c++, class, initialization

Say I have a class Foo:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

private:
    Bar* mBar;
}
```

And assume that 'Bar' is a class with a few members that need initializing.  What is the best practice to use when initializing that member?

Example 1:  Do everything in Foos constructor:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
    mBar = new Bar("some", "required", "members");
}
```

Example 2:  Create a separate initialize function:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
}

Foo::Initialize()
{
    mBar = new Bar("some", "required", "members");
}
```

Example 3:  Two part initialization, assuming 'Bar' also has a set method

```
Foo::Foo
{
    mBar = new Bar();
}

Foo::Initialize()
{
    mBar->SetMembers("some", "required", "members");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Do everything in `Foo` constructor(s)!

Do all construction and initialisation in constructors! This is known as [RAII: resource acquisition is initialisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Allocating a resource, in this case a `Foo` should initialise the resource as well. This also makes your interface easy to use: `Foo` **cannot** be used without first at least constructing a `Foo`. Once constructed, assuming it initialises everything in its constructor, it's ready to use. If you expect callers to also have to call an `Initialize` or `Set` function, you are making your class interface hard to use. How will `Foo` respond to function calls if `Initialize` hasn't first been called? Suddenly each function would need to have the following:

```
bool Foo::SomeFunction()
{
    if (!mBar->isInitialized())
        return false;

    // Do what we came here to do
    return true;
}
```

Now callers constantly have to check the return value of your functions. What if a function needed to return a value, but then had to indicate an error because `mBar` wasn't initialised?

You can see the rabbit hole goes quite deep once move away from RAII: resource allocation **is** initialisation!

From [Effective C++ Third Edition - Scott Myers](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html):

> **Item 4: Make sure that objects are initialized before they're used**
>   ...
>   the responsibility for initialization falls on constructors. The rule there is simple: make sure that all constructors initialize everything in the object

## Other advice

You should also prefer to use your constructors initializer list for constructing members:

```
Foo::Foo() : mBar(new mBar("some", "required", "members"))
{
}
```

Otherwise you will be making unnecessary copies. I also assume you have a great reason to be using a pointer. As @Niels van Eldik points out in the comments, you should use objects unless you truly need to use a pointer, and in that case you should be using whatever smart pointer best fits your needs (in this case I would verge a guess and say [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : mBar(std::make_unique<Bar>("some", "required", "members"))
    {
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> mBar;
};
```

Comment: I second that and I would also recommend to avoid the usage of pointers wherever possible. If you really need them use shared_ptr or unique_ptr. It will save you a lot of time hunting down the leaks in your code. In the example above replace     Bar* mBar; with Bar mBar;. Now you can remove the destructor as the default one will do the job AND you got ride of a bug as the default assignment operator and the default copy constructor would have caused havoc if anybody would have used them.